# Who was the person in a white cape standing behind dying Boromir in the LoTR movie?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, movie, the-lord-of-the-rings

Was it a personification of death? Or someone else?

[image: Boromir's Last Stand LOTR 1.27 [HD 1080p]]

Comment: It's just a statue.

Comment: If you down-vote, please explain why. Then I can make this and my future questions better. Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Most definitely a statue. You can see the base in this shot from slightly earlier in them film:

[image]